# Failed to load resource, (Service Unavailable) error 503

Tags: angularjs, express, heroku, npm

I have build an **angular cli** app with a **express server**,after deploying in **heroku** I try to run the app I get this error as :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

I have tried following a previous answer and added a **serve-favicon** dependency but the error persists. Here is my 
***server.js***

```
    const express = require{'express'};
const favicon = require('serve-favicon')
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
// app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/dist/favicon.ico'));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/dist/favicon.ico'));
// app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'dist','favicon.ico')));


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

//path location strategy
app.get('/*',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
})

console.log('console listeing!');
```

Favicon is located at **appname/src/favicon.ico**.
on localhost there is no problem everything loads correctly ,error appears after tring to run my heroku app after succesfully deploying.

Comment: I suspect i could be loading the favicon.ico from the wrong location

Answer (score 1):

I think server is not ready because you wrote : `require{'express'}` instead of `require('express')`.

```
const express = require('express'); // Here
var favicon = require('serve-favicon')
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
// app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/dist/favicon.ico'));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/dist/favicon.ico'));
// app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'dist','favicon.ico')));


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

//path location strategy
app.get('/*',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
})

console.log('console listeing!');
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out i have made the neccesary changes but the error stil persists

Answer (score 0):

Express also one kind of `npm module`.

So we can require by:

`const express = require('express');`

Now error won't come.

Kindly try with this solution. Its working fine for me.

Comment: on localhost there is no problem everything loads correctly ,error appears after tring to run my heroku app